# Data recovery from a partition clone

Tags: partitioning, clone

My hard drive running on Ubuntu server recently crashed and I lost the files. However I have a clone of the partition, and want to recover the files. Is it possible?

Edit: The partition is ext4 and was cloned using
cat partitionsource > partitiontarget in a new hard disk. The hard disk contains one to one copy of the partition.
I do have a backup of partition table. Will it save my day?

Answer (score 0):

To see and be able to recover files, you should mount your partition clone. If the clone is OK, you should be able to issue the command:

```
sudo mount /dev/<partitionname> /mnt
```

where `/mnt` is the directory where the data from the partition specified by `partitionname` would appear.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Melebius. I can mount it, but I only have lost+found directory.

Comment: @AmritSharma This could mean the partition was not cloned correctly. Weren’t you cloning it while it was mounted, for example? If you want to investigate further, please edit your question to contain _all_ your findings, e.g. include `ls -l` of the mounted clone.